# Azure Data Factory CI/CD without using AzureDevOps & AzureRepo

Tags: devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

With **Azure Data Factory**, mostly used with Azure Repo & for CI/CD, Azure DevOps is used.
Currently I am using Azure Data Factory, where the ***AzureRepo not configured and Azure DevOps is not to be used*** as DevOps need to be build around a framework which included ***GitLab, Concourse-CI , Terraform and other OpenSource tools***. All the JSONs are exported & available on GitLab. From there Azure Data Factory need to be created on every check-in from the ARMs/ADF-JSONs.

Let me know if anyone has came across such scenarios and is there a way to **publish Azure Data Factory without using AzureDevOps & AzureRepo**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.  The JSONs being exported are standard Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates.  These templates can be deployed from outside of Azure DevOps.

Here is how to deploy [ARM templates using GitHub Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-github-actions)

Another option would be to use [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell) `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -TemplateFile <path-to-template>`

Basically anything on how to deploy ARM templates to Azure will allow for Data Factory pipelines and infrastructure to be deployed.

Comment: The challenge I am facing is, Its not GitHub, rather its External GitLab, which has manually exported ARMs for Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Updated to include Powershell option for deployment